# CSS strange transform value from Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a transform:rotate(27deg) on a  element.

After the transform, Firefox and Chrome set this value to transform: `matrix(0.3, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0)`.

Safari sets this `value: matrix(0.3, -0.00000000000000007347880794884119, 0.00000000000000007347880794884119, 0.3, 0, 0).`

In my `js` code I check if an element is rotated or not by checking if its transform `css` equals to `matrix(0.3, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0)`, so if I use Safari I cannot check this way as Safari return this value with so many decimal figures.

Is there a way to make Safari return the same value as the other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to not rely on floating-point operations returning "perfect" results, which can be browser and CPU specific - you could split the matrix into individual numeric components (`.split` -> `parseFloat`) and check for `Math.abs(value - target) < threshold`; combine this in a handy function if this happens often enough.